Jerry Hiding Problem. How can Tom catch Jerry in an infinite days?
I am solving this question as it is interview question. The question is as follow:
On a street, there is a row of n consecutive houses (n≥3). Jerry is hiding in one of these houses. Each night, Jerry must move to an adjacent house (either left or right). If Jerry is at either end of the street, he can only move to the one adjacent house available. Each morning, Tom is allowed to search exactly one house to find Jerry. What strategy should Tom use to guarantee finding Jerry within a finite number of days?
I have tried many search strategies like 
greedy: 1, 2, 3, ..., n
search forward then backward: 1, 2, 3, ..., n, n-1, ..., 1
search each house 2 times: 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, ...
However I can't find any algorithm to ensure that I can catch Jerry. It has taken me more than one day and I cannot even think any other strategies. Please help me

Welcome to Math StackExchange. Since this is your first question on this site, I suggest you read about how to ask a good question and update yours accordingly as your question doesn't include the context, motivation, and your effort on solving the problem.

The question looks weird. (To OP) Is it your interview question? If so, you have to solve it yourself.

It's not my interview question. I found it as an interview question

(I've def seen this problem, in another skin) Hint: First consider the case when $n$ is even. Suppose Jerry is initially at an odd number house. How do we catch him?
